# Relational Query in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Assume the following data:

```
    A    B   
1   ID  Stat
2   1   1 
3   1   2 
4   2   6 
5   3   4
```

I want to be able to select the minimum and maximum values from column B for all rows that match a value in column A.  However, I cannot seem to get values for just those rows, but rather get the max/min value for all of the column.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A = 1, B:B))
```

Of course, that returns 6, while I want to return 2.

Comment: You're close. You need to use array formula: once you've typed the formula press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER.

Comment: Ugh - had tried that, but needed to also F2 first.  If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Máté said, if you use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER rather than just ENTER it should work as it will make it an array formula.